# pg_dump halting on WIndows

Tags: postgresql, backup, pg-dump

I am using the pg_dump command in the following way, on my Windows machine:

```bash
pg_dump -h "jumbo.db.elephantsql.com" -U "hytxlzju" -p "5432" -f "ebDumping.sql" --verbose "hytxlzju" > "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\bin\extremeBlueDB.sql"
```

I don't get any logs and I cannot see the file being created at the specified location. Any idea?

Comment: Are there any error messages? Is the process consuming CPU? How long did you wait?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[Answer]

```
 C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\bin>  pg_dump -h "jumbo.db.elephantsql.com" -U "hytxlzju" -p "5432" --verbose --role "hytxlzju" --format
p --encoding "SQL_ASCII" "hytxlzju" > "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\bin\extremeBlueDB.sql"
```